# JFormattedTextField.getValue is returning not formatted value

Tags: java, swing, floating-point, jformattedtextfield

I would like to have `JFormattedTextField` to only accept numbers, that is a double number with a maximum of 2 fraction digits. I read the information present on `JFormattedTextField` tutorial on Oracle page that lead me to the solution presented below.

But field does not work as intended. Displaying it fine, it will always cut after the 2nd fraction digit, but when I call: `((Number)field.getValue).doubleValue()` it returns more then 2 fraction digits if user input them. (Example: If you put `1,333` into the field, it will display `1,33` but value will be `1,333`

Here's the code:

```
private void setFormatters() {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(numberFormat);
    numberFormatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

    sizeTF.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(
            numberFormatter
    ));

    depthTF.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(
            numberFormatter
    ));
}
```

Fields are declared here:

```
private JFormattedTextField sizeTF = new JFormattedTextField();
private JFormattedTextField depthTF = new JFormattedTextField();
```

I'd be glad If you could provide me with a solution to my problem as well explain why the above code reflects in such behavior.

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). (spoiler alert) Floating point numbers cannot be represented accurately in binary. That's the reason why we leave them to do their stuff internally, and only ever muick about with formatted representations at **time of display**. So suck it up, get used to it, and format at time of display or printing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well thx for the info, tho I knew all the stuff about floats, but was surprised that formatter 1st converts and then does stuff to display so it is not good for accepting a certain format value. Well I did a workaround using `DocumentFilter ` with `JTextField` :)